# run git update-server-info on the server?

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to download a source code from code.google.com using git command but getting the following error

```
 git clone https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/

 Initialized empty Git repository in /afs/.cpiv.com/techhome/john.f/Desktop/dolphin-player/.git/

  fatal: https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player//info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

 john.f@4wing13:~/Desktop$ git update-server-info

 fatal: Not a git repository
```

Any one please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to clone from it. Update your git to more recent versions ( atleast 1.7+ ) as it might not support the newer Smart HTTP in older versions.

Comment: Thanks manoj ,,Can you please tell me know,how to update git to 1.7